# Video stream slow @ receiver side when processing

Tags: python, opencv

```
import time
import threading
import cv2
import imagezmq
import cv2
from flask import Flask, Response
import emotion_detection_copy, mouth_open_copy
import objectdetection
import final_recogcopy
import predict
import person_and_phone_copy, head_pose_copy
import eye_tracker_copy
import predict
import datetime

image_hub = imagezmq.ImageHub()
while True:
    cam_id, frame = image_hub.recv_image()
    print("before", datetime.datetime.now())
    # predict.predict_labels(frame) # working fine
    t1 = 
    threading.Thread(target=final_recogcopy.recog(frame),args())
    t2 = 
   threading.Thread(target=objectdetection.object_detection(frame), args=())  # working fine
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=emotion_detection_copy.detect_emotion(frame), args=())  # working fine
    t4 = threading.Thread(target=person_and_phone_copy.person_and_phone_count(frame), args=())  # working fine
    t5 = threading.Thread(target=head_pose_copy.head_position(frame), args=())  # working fine    cv2.waitKey(1)
    t6 = threading.Thread(target=eye_tracker_copy.gaze_detection(frame))
     final_recogcopy.recog(frame)
    t7 = threading.Thread(target=mouth_open_copy.mouth_opening_detection(frame))
    
x = datetime.datetime.now()

    #print(start)
    t2.start()
    start1 = time.time()
    t3.start()
    start2 = time.time()
    t4.start()
    start3 = time.time()
    t5.start()
    start4 = time.time()
    t6.start()
    start5 = time.time()
    t1.start()
    start = time.time()
    # t7.start()

    t1.join()
    y = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("diff is", y - x)
    end = time.time()
    print(end)
    print("Total time taken T1", start - end)
    t2.join()
    end1 = time.time()
    print("Total time taken T2", start1 - end1)
    t3.join()
    end2 = time.time()
    print("Total time taken T3", start2 - end2)
    t4.join()
    end3 = time.time()
    print("Total time taken T4", start3 - end3)
    t5.join()
    end4 = time.time()
    print("Total time taken T5", start4 - end4)
    t6.join()
    end5 = time.time()
    print("Total time taken T6", start5 - end5)
    # t7.join()


    print("after", datetime.datetime.now())
    cv2.imshow(cam_id, frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
    image_hub.send_reply(b'OK')
```

I am using imagezmq for streaming of video in python from my webcam using opencv. when i am streaming normal video to the receiver side its normal at receiver side but when processing like object detection etc at receiver side the video will not like near to realtime its very messy and slow . plzzzz help.

```
Thanks
```

Comment: processing takes time. that's why things run slower.

Comment: yeah, Christoph Rackwitz its taking 11 sec to process frame ,i also used multithreading but same problem exists. How can i proceed to avoid this .

Comment: you could start by showing exactly what you do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Video is usually at 30fps. 11 seconds is far too long and even if you multi-thread, you'll get a backlog building up. Some questions to consider: Do you need to process this video live or can you save to a file and process it offline? Do you need to process every single video frame? Do you actually need ALL of those processes to define your problem? What hardware are you running on (can it be improved)?

Comment: I have to process live video, yes we have to process every frame, I am running this on Param Shavak which is Supercomputer in a Box system in a table top model
Powered with 2 multicore CPUs each with minimum 12 cores
2 numbers of accelerator cards
3 Tera-Flops peak computing power with 8 TB of storage
Easy to deploy solution with no additional datacenter infrastructure
Pre-loaded with parallel programming development tools and libraries
Preinstalled tools for scheduling and resource management
Video Tutorials, learning materials and user manuals etc.
Indigenous HPC portal- CHReME

Comment: Ok, it doesn't sound like you're going to get a faster computer to run this on. Is your code definitely using all available computing power (i.e. are all CPUs and cores maxed out when you run the code)? If it is, your only option is to try to optimise the code, but be aware that open source deep learning solutions are not always fast enough to run in real time. Consider what you can easily cut down on: frames per second, width/height of frame. Optimised Python code is not necessarily going to give you real-time video processing, so you might need to look into Cython or something.